# Formating SD cards from the GUI

Tags: sd-card

Folks,

I really like ubuntu!  Really I do!  However I'd just like to format my SD Cards and have them work.

I use 32, 64, and 128Gig SD cards for everything.  Moving Zoom files, Photos, and Document files between other Linux or windows and sometimes even Mac.  I use SD cards in my several trail cams.

I format them on a windows 7 machine (fast format) as Fat or Exfat they work fine. Some times I need to do erase but for the most part fast format works.  If I format them (Fat 32 and not erase) in UBUNTU 20.04 they don't work in my trail cam. AND my trail cam won't format them.  Of course it don't tell me that so when I go back 2 weeks later there are no photos on the card! I never use command line to format because it is far to hard to tell what disk I'm formatting. Gparted and Disks are OK but I prefer to right click on the disk under "files" and select format.

If I take a working trail cam card and format it with UBUNTU 20.04 (again erase is not checked) when it is done I can't create "folders" or copy files to it.  No one else can either!  And it never works again in the trail cam until I format (fat or exfat) it with windows 7.  Then I can create folders and copy file to it in UBUNTU.

I have noticed that under properties in UBUNTU that the bottom line tells me I don't have permissions even though I just formated it. I don't see any options fix permissions!

Also in UBUNTU if I choose to "erase" again under "files" and using right click the GUI never gives me any indication it is formatting the SD card but if I remove it then I'm into partition land before I ever get it to work again.

Can you tell me how to fix my problem?  At least tell me how to set permissions when formating from the GUI, Gparted or Disks.

Comment: What if you just delete the photo's/folders from the SD-cards in Ubuntu? Not formating.

Comment: Ubuntu can read and write disks and partitions that use the familiar FAT32 and NTFS formats, but by default it uses a more advanced format called Ext4. This format is less likely to lose data in the event of a crash, and it can support large disks or files

Comment: SD cards are usually formatted with FAT32 filesystem (at least that's how Windows formats them). Cameras expect this filesystem on the card. Did you choose the FAT32 option when you formatted the card in Ubuntu? If not, Ubuntu formatted the card with its default filesystem which is ext4. Cameras can't recognize nor use that format. Windows can't too. So, if you want your SD cards to be "universally" compatible, you have to format them with FAT32.

Comment: Just to make it clear. When I format in UBUNTU I use Fat32.  When I format in windows 7 I use exFAT (NOT NTFS) Fat32 is not listed. Note: When I can't write to the SD card in UBUNTU the at the bottom of the properties window (right click on the Drive under "Files" and select "properties" Under "permissions" tab I find "You are not the owner.......".  The trail cam mandates that I format it in the cam.  SD cards right out of the box always work in what ever machine I put them in. I  just can't format SD cards on any machine and use them in another machine.  How do I fix this?

Comment: You can avoid the permission issues if you use Disks. If any other it'll be owned by root but you can easily change ownership with a single command (chown).

Comment: I really don't want to do this from terminal.  It bad enough that you can get the wrong disk in Gparted or Disks but in terminal it is far too risky for me.  I need a solution from the GUI preferably under "nautilus-files".  Had this in windows premium but now only have the home version which doesn't have a security tab under disk properties.  Right now I have go to Gparted and  delete the partition then make a new, format as Fat32 then move the card to windows and quick format as exFAT.  That works but Geeeeeee!